# I get and Error 500 when using case statements to include database connection files

Tags: asp-classic, include, case

```
Select Case thisPage
    Case "Calendar"
        %><!--#include file='ConnCal.asp' --><% OPEN_DB mySQL, 8 

    Case "User"
        %><!--#include file='ConnDB.asp' --><% OPEN_DB mainSQL, 8

End Select
```

The connection string opens and functions properly for the "calendar" page. As a one-item case statement it works but when I add another case statement (shown above) I get an Error500.

Since I am certain that the Calendar-case works I've tried copying its content into the User-case and that breaks it too... any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Solution found! It was not the case or the include that was the problem. It was the conflicting DIMs in the files being included. Ugh! False alarm.

Comment: Do you have friendly error messages enabled?  This should have pinpointed this issue immediately.  If you don't here's a good link on how to set this up. http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp